# ClassNotFoundException for skinny war

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, war, ear

I'm facing class loading problem with class loading in my skinny `war` packaged within `ear`.
Where there are also other ejb modules packaged. Some can be loaded via spring while some not.

Imagine following scenario:

```
someApp.ear
|- someEJBs1.jar
|- someEJBs2.jar
...
|- someEJBsX.jar
|- someWar.war
```

If I try from the someWar.war to access via spring some classes present in:

- someEJBs1.jar it works
- but for those in someEJBs2.jar I'm getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

No clue where the problem is.
My `MANIFEST.MF` doesn't contain any classpath information at all.

I was already thinking if there there any way to see during runtime (maybe during debugging) the classes loaded, or possibly the classpath provided for the particular war file?

I'm running in glassfish 3.1.1 (that is a requirement, no change on this one is possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following debug functions in your code:

```
    //Prints the Root directory
    public static void printPWD() {
        File dir1 = new File(".");
        try {
            System.out.println("Current dir : " + dir1.getCanonicalPath());
            dir1 = null;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


     // Prints all files on the ClassPath to the system.out

    public static void printClasspathFiles() {
        ClassLoader sysClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        // Get the URLs
        URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) sysClassLoader).getURLs();

        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(urls[i].getFile());
        }
    }

//prints the classpath to system.out
print printClasspath(){
       System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
}
```

To get all loaded classes, the getAllLoadedClasses Method would be useful. [See Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses%28%29)

Comment: OK, tested it, but it didn't provide any usefull information to me to be honest. As I was not able to see all the jars that are available for classes to load from. But rather only some base glassfish jars. Anyway marking as correct, as it seem to be all I can get from the classloader. Moreover you answered my question, no doubt on that :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally found the root cause, I overlooked the problem of wrong package definition in my spring xml configs. :)

I should read the error messages properly, I guess. And double check whatever I assume is correct. (well that is nothing new in my case)

Now it works for me.